# RequireJS bundles load timeout

Tags: requirejs, amd

I'm getting a load timeout from some of my modules when using bundles. The complete bundled source contains the script for the modules, but the timeout occurs anyway. Other modules in the bundle don't cause a timeout error.

Any bright ideas? The error is

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules:
>   system/mvc/collection,system/mvc/router,system/mvc/view

My configuration looks like this:

```
    requirejs.config({
            "baseUrl" : "/UIAssets/js/",
            "paths" : {
                "{0}" : "pc/0.6.5210.18633/fr"
            },
            "bundles" : {
"http://mydomain.com/0.6.5210.18633.combo?/UIAssets/js/system/mvc/model.js&/UIAssets/js/system/mvc/collection.js&/UIAssets/js/system/mvc/router.js&/UIAssets/js/system/mvc/view.js&/UIAssets/js/UI/views/Home.js&/UIAssets/js/pc/0.6.5210.18633/fr/Templates/shared/myPartial.js&/UIAssets/js/pc/0.6.5210.18633/fr/Templates/shared/copyright.js" : [
    "system/mvc/router", 
    "system/mvc/model", 
    "system/mvc/collection", 
    "{0}/Routes", 
    "{0}/Resources/Routes", 
    "system/mvc/view", 
    "system/helpers/stringify",
    "system/helpers/format",
    "UI/views/Home", 
    "{0}/Templates/shared/myPartial", 
    "{0}/Templates/shared/copyright"]
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a high tolerance margin to see if it fixes the issue

```
requirejs.config({

    waitSeconds: 16,
    ...

});
```

If it doesn't, then something's broken inside the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same timeout issue, without any script errors. The reason turned out to be requiring the same script in two different ways in the same code base (but not the same file):

```html
var somemodule = require('somemodule');
```

and

```html
var somemodule = require('js/somemodule.js')
```

while I had the path configured like this:

```html
require.config({
  ...

  "paths" : {

    "somemodule" : "js/somemodule.js"
  },
  ...

});
```

So I had two copies of the same code being used, which somehow messed things up. Possibly some state was set in both copies separately?